# Why Bash have such strange behavior regarding to the startup file

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, unix

I found how bash read startup files :

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Why is that - I mean this queue  of "~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile".   (And this logic - "if one of this file exist the other ones are not read at all")

I really don't understand point of that, why we need that much mess. Why Bash don't just read just one "global" and one "user specific" startup file ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that there are different ways to use a shell, there are different shells and you may want to share / re-use some options (or not!).

For example, all shells derived from Bourne Shell read `~/.profile`. So if you want to share options between `/bin/sh`, `/bin/ksh` and `/bin/bash`, put them there.

But then, you may want different options for BASH and KSH. In that case, use `.bash_profile` and `.kshrc` respectively and have them source the common `~/.profile`.

Using the rules above, you can fine-tune your shell's setup. It will first load the config file which is most suitable for its purpose. In said config file, you can then chose to load others to inherit whatever your want. If you only use `.profile`, then that makes it easy to switch between different shells.

I'm not sure about the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login`; maybe this is a leftover from a bug or a change in the design.

Login scripts are executed only for login shells (i.e. the first shell a system creates when a user logs in; all other shells and processes will be children of it). The login shell contains things like global variables which you want everywhere. A common example is the ID of the SSH agent so you can load keys in any shell and they will work for every process of the same user. It doesn't make sense to do that for every shell that you start.

On the other hand, it doesn't make sense to define a prompt for non-interactive shells, so this goes into a different config script.

Comment: So it is basically like this: Bash search for most "suitable" files, if it found some "bash specific" file  like -> "~/.bash_profile"  it thinks : Hey! If user defined specific file to the bash, he now will take care of sourcing other things like ~/.profile if he [user] want it - And because of this reasoning it stops reading the following files in the queue ?

Comment: Yes. It's a kind of simple OO mechanism to extend / inherit config options between shells and use cases.

Comment: Well, for me OO mechanism would be when, it just read this files in order.  Assuming that the LAST ONE could override everything what was defined before (somewhat like :  ~/.bash_login extends ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile extends  ~/.bash_login)

Comment: I think having both `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login` is for the benefit of `csh` users, for whom `.login` is the equivalent of `.profile`. `.bash_profile` would take precedence as the more "`bash`-like" of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a number of different ways of being started and each of these allows for different configuration. These include, interactive, non-interactive, login, non-login, sh and any combination of these.

You are possibly confusing what would be easier for you and what would be easier for someone else with different requirements. This is pretty much the linux / unix way.

EDIT:

The reason for the loading order of the files is that .bash_login and .profile are synonyms for .bash_profile. These come from C shells **.login** file and bourne shell and korn shells **.profile**. As I understand it this ordering allows for backward compatibility (unsuccessful in the case of C shell) with these other shells.

Comment: You answered really vaguely.  I asked "what" is sense of this, not "wether" it have any sense.

Comment: Are you asking for a justification of this mechanism? If so, it's as I said, it's for flexibility of use.

Comment: I asked specifically why is this queue ->  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile    and logic of Bash  that goes : "if either of those files exist and are readable DON'T read next in the queue"

Comment: I've updated the answer to try and answer this specific point.